# Xamarin.Android: Retrieving selected ListView element in AlertDialog

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I'm creating a calendar in Xamarin.Android that shows you a calendar of dates.  On clicking a date, it grabs the list of events on that day for display in a custom adapter in a `ListView`, all within an `AlertDialog`.

What I want to do is have it so when the user clicks an event in the list, it grabs information from that event (specifically, a URL to the event's web page) and then allows the `PositiveButton` of the `AlertDialog` to open that site with a new `Activity`.

I have no trouble creating the `AlertDialog` and placing the `ListView` in it and populating the list with the events.  I used the code [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509738/how-can-i-display-listview-in-xamarin-android-alert-dialog) with some slight modifications.

I know the event is selected as the `android:listSelector` property in the listview's layout file is firing as expected.  However, I just can't figure out how to access the click event or grab the position of the item selected to access its data.  In another `Activity` which is just a `ListView`, I just do the following:

```
HistoricSitesListView.ItemClick += HistoricSitesListView_ItemClick;
void HistoricSiesListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{ code here }
```

This grabs the info for that list's individual items fine.  But attempting to do the same thing with the `dialogView` object gives me an `View has no definition for ItemClick` error.  Making dialogView a ListView and casting the inflater gives an InvalidCast exception.

My modified code is as follows:

```
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EventsListLayout, null);
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    using (var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
    {
        dialog.SetView(dialogView);
        dialog.SetPositiveButton("More Info", (s, a) =>
        {
            if (currentEventURL != "null")
            {
                Intent eventIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(currentEventURL));
                StartActivity(eventIntent);
            }
        });
        dialog.SetNegativeButton("Close", (s, a) => { });
        alertDialog = dialog.Create();
    }
    var adapter = new EventModelAdapter(this, EventStringList);
    dialogView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.eventListView).Adapter = adapter;

    dialogView.ItemClick += dialogView_ItemClick;

    void dialogView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        EventModel clickedEvent = EventStringList[e.Position];
        currentEventURL = clickedEvent.EventURL;
    };
    alertDialog.Show();
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

In the AlertDialog.Builder, I did this:

```
dialog.SetView(dialogView);
EventListView = dialogView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.eventListView);
```

and then outside of it,

```
EventListView.Adapter = adapter;
EventListView.ItemClick += EventListView_ItemClick;

void EventListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        currentEventURL = EventStringList[e.Position].EventURL;
    }
```

I had tried this earlier but got null reference exceptions.  I thought it was thinking the adapter or the items were null, but I just had to scope the view to the dialogView, because it was looking for eventListView in the Calendar layout, not the EventList layout.